# Want to get a pointer/reference to an object from a CCommand CAccessor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

```
    CCommand<CAccessor<CMyClass> > rsDetails;
    rsDetails.m_IdxPrj = pDoc->m_dbId;
    if (rsDetails.Open(session) == S_OK)
    {
        rsDetails.ClearRecord();
        if (rsDetails.MoveNext() == S_OK)
        {
            CMyClassBase* data = ?
        }
    }
```

I have something similar to the above code where I am getting a load of data using a CCommand CAccessor. I have a class that handles the param map and column map, etc, and then a parent/base class that has the variables in it.

I'm not very fluent in C++, so apologies if I'm missing something that's seen as "obvious", but I can't figure out how to get a pointer/reference to MyClass, or MyClassBase in order to then pass that to a function for further processing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CMyClassBase* details = dynamic_cast<CMyClassBase*>(rsDetails.m_pAccessor);
```

It was fairly obvious, sorry!
..although if this isn't a good solution, or if there is a better solution then please let me know.

Comment: What is the rationale for using a C-style cast followed by a `dynamic_cast`? The C-style cast will break, what the `dynamic_cast` is trying to protect you from. Keep in mind that if you don't know why your code works, it doesn't.

Comment: As I saw it, the m_pAccessor is CMyClass, I just had to identify it as such...the dynamic was to upcast is to the parent class. Where have I misunderstood this?

Comment: ...ok, so I see now that I can remove the C-style cast and dynamic cast the accessor straight to the base. I didn't want to assume I could cut corners and didn't know the dynamic cast was clever enough for that. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: You can immediately assign a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to a base class, without any casts. `dynamic_cast` is for downcasts, i.e. casting a pointer to a base class to a pointer to a more derived class. (Every occurrence of 'pointer' can be replaced with 'pointer or reference'.)